# How to create swipe loop with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

There are several options that can switch through the click button. But if I click on to last option or first option it will find nothing. How can I create a loop when I click the last option it can return to the first.

```js
$('.pie-btn-prev').on('click', function() {
  $('.is-current').removeClass('active is-current').prev().addClass('active is-current')
});
$('.pie-btn-next').on('click', function() {

  $('.is-current').removeClass('active is-current').next().addClass('active is-current')
})
```

```html
<div class="icon-box">
  <div class="pie-icon icon-1">
    <i class="fas fa-alien-monster"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pie-icon icon-2">
    <i class="fas fa-alien-monster"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pie-icon icon-3">
    <i class="fas fa-alien-monster"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pie-icon icon-4">
    <i class="fas fa-alien-monster"></i>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-box">
  <div class="pie-btn-prev">
    <i class="fal fa-long-arrow-left"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pie-btn-next">
    <i class="fal fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Check if the next/prev exists.